# Order by one column and then by another column

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d5fc/6) and the table looks like below

```
TicketId    EmployeeId  BookingRef  DepartureDate   DepartureTime      
1           1110341     8662225387  2017-10-16      14:00:00.0000000    
2           1110341     8662225388  2017-10-17      14:36:00.0000000    
3           1110341     8662225388  2017-10-17      21:39:00.0000000    
4           1110341     8662225389  2017-10-12      17:15:00.0000000    
5           1110341     8662225390  2017-10-12      18:42:00.0000000    
6           1110341     8662225390  2017-10-16      14:15:00.0000000
```

I want to order it by DepartureDate, DepartureTime and BookingRef however related BookingRef should be partitioned together So the above result should look like

```
TicketId    EmployeeId  BookingRef  DepartureDate   DepartureTime      
4           1110341     8662225389  2017-10-12      17:15:00.0000000    
5           1110341     8662225390  2017-10-12      18:42:00.0000000    
6           1110341     8662225390  2017-10-16      14:15:00.0000000    
1           1110341     8662225387  2017-10-16      14:00:00.0000000
2           1110341     8662225388  2017-10-17      14:36:00.0000000    
3           1110341     8662225388  2017-10-17      21:39:00.0000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a subquery to do your ordering, something like this;

```
SELECT 
  t.*
FROM Ticket t
JOIN (SELECT BookingRef, MIN(DepartureDate) MinDeparture FROM Ticket GROUP BY BookingRef) sub
  ON t.BookingRef = sub.BookingRef
ORDER BY sub.MinDeparture ASC, t.BookingRef ASC
```

Which gives the output that you've shown. See it in the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d5fc/25)

This is going to order by the minimum DepartureTime for each BookingRef.

Answer (score 0):

You want to 'Group By'

> SELECT column_names FROM table_name WHERE condition **GROUP BY
>   BookingRef** ORDER BY column_name;

Comment: As Group by expects all columns in the select list, adding order by didn't work, for example, Select TicketID, EmployeeID, BookingRef, DepartureDate, DepartureTime, ArrivalDate, ArrivalTime 
from Ticket
Group by TicketID, EmployeeID, BookingRef, DepartureDate, DepartureTime, ArrivalDate, ArrivalTime 
Order by EmployeeID, DepartureDate, DepartureTime;